# Passing multiple lines to terminal at once?

Tags: shell, applescript

I am trying to use AppleScript to pass multiple lines to the Terminal. What I am trying to do is change the video input & output with one click. Here is what I have so far, but it seems like only the first line executes and everything else is ignored. I have tried using multiple lines of `do script`, but that opens a new window for each. Any suggestions?

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "nc xxx.xxx.x.xxx 9990
        VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:
        0 3
        1 15
        2 15"
    end tell

    return input

end run
```

Comment: Why are you using Applescript and Terminal at all? Why not just make a `bash` script whch can do netcat perfectly well itself, and multi-line input.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `nc` command before, so I'm going to assume that the format you've demonstrated is viable.  Proceeding along these lines, if you need a physical *Terminal* window to be open for this command, then multiline bash commands can be sent in a couple of ways:

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "nc xxx.xxx.x.xxx 9990 << EOF
        VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:
        0 3
        1 15
        2 15
        EOF"
    end tell
```

Or:

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "nc xxx.xxx.x.xxx 9990 \\
            VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING: \\
            0 3 \\
            1 15 \\
            2 15"
    end tell
```

If you **don't** require *Terminal* to be open for this command to run, then you can use `do shell script` instead:

```
    do shell script "nc xxx.xxx.x.xxx 9990 \\
        VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING: \\
        0 3 \\
        1 15 \\
        2 15"
```

(Note that there is no `tell` block, as `do shell script` is one of AppleScript's standard additions.)

When using the Bash line continuation character `\` as I have done above in the last two code snippets, *Script Editor* will reformat the multi-line string onto a single line, replacing linefeeds with `\n`.  It looks ugly, but it represents the same string.  Alternatively, you can concatenate multiple strings like this:

```
    do shell script "nc xxx.xxx.x.xxx 9990 \\" & linefeed & ¬
        "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING: \\" & linefeed & ¬
        "0 3 \\" & linefeed & ¬
        "1 15 \\" & linefeed & ¬
        "2 15"
```

Comment: Found out how to get the multi lines. However, now I cannot get the keystroke return to work. I get an error every time. Any way to keystroke return two times? The following is not working:

keystroke return in window 1

Comment: Update your question with the code you're using to send the multi-line command, and explain why you need to send a `keystroke return`.